# How to compare columns in pandas and create new column with yes or no

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
    A           B           C           D
0   0.397333    Xor         0.569748    0.406415
1   0.319684    x           0.159117    0.522648
2   0.778038    0.486989    x           x
3   0.549993    0.896913    0.960814    0.430113
4   0.251655    0.802137    Xand        0.218265
```

Here I need to compare all four columns and I need to have a new `column E` where I will have my new information.

I need to check if any of the four columns contains `x` than `Column E` will have value `Yes` else `No`.

Output

```
    A           B           C           D          E
0   0.397333    Xor         0.569748    0.406415   No
1   0.319684    x           0.159117    0.522648   Yes
2   0.778038    0.486989    x           x          Yes
3   0.549993    0.896913    0.960814    0.430113   No
4   x           0.802137    Xand        0.218265   Yes
```

I want to use where clause here but I am not able to do that and lambda also I am not able to understand how should I write.

Here is my code:

```
def YorN(stri):
    if stri =='x':
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['E'] = np.where(YorN(df.B) | YorN(df.C) | YorN(df.D)| YorN(df.A), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Edit 1**
My other columns may contain some other variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison func won't work as you've found out, you're trying to compare a scalar with an array. Anyway you can call `apply` and pass `axis=1` to process the df row-wise. Convert the dtype to `str` so that you can use the vectorised `str.contains` with `any` to produce a boolean series and use this as the arg for `np.where` and return 'yes' or 'no' when `True` or `False` respectively:

```
In [8]:
df['E'] = np.where(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('x').any(), axis=1), 'yes', 'no')
df

Out[8]:
          A         B         C         D    E
0  0.397333  0.245596  0.569748  0.406415   no
1  0.319684         x  0.159117  0.522648  yes
2  0.778038  0.486989         x         x  yes
3  0.549993  0.896913  0.960814  0.430113   no
4  0.251655  0.802137  0.024341  0.218265   no
```

**EDIT**

Answer still works:

```
In [10]:
df['E'] = np.where(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('x').any(), axis=1), 'yes', 'no')
df

Out[10]:
          A         B         C         D    E
0  0.397333       Xor  0.569748  0.406415   no
1  0.319684         x  0.159117  0.522648  yes
2  0.778038  0.486989         x         x  yes
3  0.549993  0.896913  0.960814  0.430113   no
4  0.251655  0.802137      Xand  0.218265   no
```

Comment: sorry EdChum but if I have some other information than those number than I can't use `.contains`. But thanks for replying

Comment: Unless you post a question with representative data and information it makes it very annoying for SO users to waste time answering a pointless question also you've not fully explained why my solution does not work

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question a bit. Now if I use contains `x` then I thought it will not work.

Comment: Sorry @EdChum if you are not angry can I make one more change, there are more than one column and I need to particulary check only on this four column. Really Sorry. If you say yes than I will change otherwise its OK. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Post a new question, the etiquette on SO is 1 problem per question, SO is not a forum, it is not a code writing service, it is not a place to ask any specific user for help. You can't keep incrementing your requirements.

Comment: I am really sorry, I have a huge table and I couldn't copy everything that's why I made it a short one here. Really sorry. I will keep that in mind from now on.Because I was trying with the particular column that's why I posted only that four column. :(